Navigate to a particular page of a pdf which is rendered from a link in a next js app
I need to integrate a pdf viewer to my nextjs application. I have tried the google drive viewer in the <iframe> tag which looks like this:
  <iframe
    src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${pdfView.url}&embedded=true`}
    className="w-full h-[calc(100%-3rem)]"
  ></iframe>

I want a button in my nextjs app which will navigate to a specific page of the pdf. If it is not possible with the iframe docs viewer of google what is another alternative and how to do it?
I haven't yet tried using react-pdf. If this is possible with react pdf then please provide me the code
